# Low Power Even at Max Rev

Tags: motorcycle, power, acceleration, backfire

I have a 200cc motorcycle which i use for daily ride to my work for just around 20 minutes only. I always had this problem of having low power after I decelerate using engine brake. Here is the scenario.

When I decelerate using engine break especially in downhill terrain and rev the throttle, there is a change in the acceleration power and the sound of the exhaust.
For example, i use only 1/8 of the throttle power usually to attain 60kph. But after the problem, it takes 2/4 to 3/4 of the throttle to attain 60kph on the same gear. Another thing is the exhaust sounds not the usual like it has a lot of air and there are popping sound everytime i use engine brake when it has low power and the normal will come back after some minutes. I dont know whats happening and i already took my bike to the mechanic and explained what happened but he also cant diagnose the problem since everytime i took the bike to the mech, the problem is not present lol. Btw, my bike is just 6 months old. What seems to be the problem of my bike? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Just so we know, what is the year/make/model of your motorcycle?

Comment: 2017 model, motorstar z200s

Answer (score 1):

Lot's of popping on decel often means the bike is running lean. Is your bike carburated? If so, I would start out by cleaning the carb and checking the jetting.

Comment: yes its carburated . thanks ill try some mechs to tune my carb !

Comment: Make sure to report back with the results! Also, like mentioned above, could you tell us wat the year/make/model of your motorcycle is?